# Connection to Xamarin.iOS Build Host failed. Double click here to attempt to reconnect/select a server

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

While loading any new project in Visual Studio 2012 and connecting with Xamarin Build host provider, it gives error "Connection to Xamarin.iOS Build Host failed. Double click here to attempt to reconnect/select a server"

Followed below mentioned steps but none worked.

1. Tried to unpair and pair again from VS 2012 and MAC Build host provider
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Xamarin\MonoTouchVS\KnownServers remove this key from Registry but I was not able to find this registry
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Xamarin\MonoTouchVS\MonoTouchBuildServerAddress remove this registry key but didn't help.
4. Someone suggested to disable proxy by following below steps.

I had the some problem, all was configured well but got the same error. The solution for me, was to disable the proxy! on the windows machine

Hope that will help you

Could anyone please suggest how to disable proxy and on which PC Windows / MAC? And let me know if that helps you to resolve the issue?

Thanks..

Any other solution to get this issue resolved?

==========================

Updates on 24 July, 2014

Solution to my question above I found is: Network connection and constant PING to my MAC PC was broken and thats what causing the problem to connect to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This works for my machine but not sure about yours.

1. Go to Xamarin Studio on your Mac, update Xamarin.
2. Reboot your Mac (just to be absolutely sure)
3. Startup the iOS Build Host on Mac.
4. Go to VS on your PC, when VS is trying to connect to the Build Host, make sure the IP address is correct (i.e. your Mac/build host machine IP).
5. If the IP Address is incorrect (which is my case), try manual connect by entering your Build Host IP Address and try to connect again.

Good luck.